# ansible ssh permission denied

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ansible

I'm generated ssh key, and copy it to remote server. When I try to ssh to that server everything works fine:

```
ssh user@ip_address
```

User is not a root. If I try to ssh throw ansible:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
```

with ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: web
  remote_user: user
  tasks:
    - name: test connection
      ping:
```

and hosts file:

```
[web]
192.168.0.103
```

I got error:

```
...
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: when you say "everything works fine", does it ask for password or not? Rerun with `-vvvv` and post the output..

Answer (score 9):

Ansible is using different key compared to what you are using to connect to that 'web' machine.

You can explicitly configure ansible to use a specific private key by

```
private_key_file=/path/to/key_rsa
```

as mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file) Make sure that you authorize that key which ansible uses, to the remote user in remote machine with `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/key_rsa.pub user@webmachine_ip_address`

Comment: I also had this problem and using ssh-copy-id for each host did the trick

Comment: The configuration at /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg is one but not the only place where alternative ssh keys can be defined. When I faced this problem, the cause was in the inventory files, where individual keys to use for each host were defined.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got similar error while running ansible playbook when host changed it's fingerprint. I found this, trying to establish ssh connection from command line. So, after running `ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R my_ip` this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Run the play as below. by default ansible plays using root.
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -u user
If you still get the error, run below and paste the out-put here.
ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -u user -vvv

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether there is authorized is saved on ip 192.168.0.103 with
`cat /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`
if there is  no ip then copy id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys with command

`vim /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`